# Is the right-hand derivative equal to the right-hand limit of the derivative?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f(x)$ be a function on the interval $[a,b]$ which is differentiable on $(a,b)$. Is it true that
$$f'_+(a)=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a^+}f'(x)$$
if both limits exist? Darboux's theorem seems to imply that it is indeed the case, but my idea of proof is somewhat fishy (uses an ``odd extension" of $f(x)$, etc.) Can anyone confirm or disprove that I'm right? Thanks.

Here $f'_+(a):=\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$.

Comment: Definition added. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean $h \to 0^+$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem ​ ​

Comment: Yes, thanks again! Edited it in.

Comment: [Derivative of a function can have discontinuities of the second kind only](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1115395/721644).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As hinted by @Ricky Demer, the MVT is what you want to use. Here's why.

Suppose that $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$ and that  $\lim_{x\to a+} f'(x)=L\in{\mathbb R}$. Let $(h_n)$ be a positive sequence tending to $0$. Then it follows from the MVT that for each $n$ there exists $c_n \in (a,a+h_n)$ such that
$$\frac{f(a+h_n) - f(a)}{h_n}= f'(c_n).$$
By letting $n\to\infty$, the righthand side converges to $L$, and therefore so does the lefthand side. Since this limit is independnet of the sequence $(h_n)$, it folllows that $f_+'(a)$ exists and coincides with $\lim_{x\to a+} f'(x)$.

Also observe that this argument shows that the only discontinuities of a derivative are of the second kind (never removable or first kind (limit exists but is different from value)).

Comment: [Derivative of a function can have discontinuities of the second kind only](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1115395/721644), yes (:

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is right when the function is differentible, that is $f'$ is exists.
In this case bouth $f'_+$ and $f'_\_$ are exists and equal and there is no problem.
If $f$ is only have right derivative there is no $f'$ and it is not the case.

Comment: I added the condition that $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$.

Comment: If the function  f  is differentiable there is no problem, the definition of right hand derivative is right hand limit of $\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$

Comment: In fact, the mean value theorem is also valid when $f$ has only right-derivative in $(a,b)$. This is obtained by repeating the standard proorf word-by-word, so the result above also holds under this weaker assumption.