# Continuity of the derivative of a function defined as an integral.

Tags: integration, derivatives, continuity, epsilon-delta

fellow mathematicians. 
I am trying to establish the following result:

Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be integrable in $[a,b]$ and let $c\in(a,b)$. Consider the function
$$
F(x):=\int_{a}^{x}{f(t)\,dt}\,\text{such that}\,x\in[a,b]
$$

If $f$ is differentiable at $c$, then $F'$ is continuous at $c$.

So far I've worked this out:

Since $f'(c)$ exists, $f$ is differentiable at $c$, then $f$ is continuous at $c$. By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus $F(x)$ is continuous and $F$ is differentiable at $c$, moreover:

$$
F'(c)=f(c)
$$

Now, $F(x)$ is a continuous function *and* is differentiable at a point $c$. Does that mean that $F(x)$ is differentiable in a neighbourhood of $c$? If that is the case, I could use the epsilon-delta definition of continuity to prove that $F'(x)$ is continuous at $c$. For example:

$F'(x)$ is continous at $c$ if the following is satisfied:
$$
\lim_{x\to c}{F'(x)}=F'(c) \Longleftrightarrow \forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \delta > 0(0<|x-c|<\delta \implies |F'(c)-F'(x)|<\epsilon)
$$

And $F'(x)$ would make sense in a neighbourhood of $c$, then I could use the definition to prove the continuity of $F'(x)$ at $c$.

Thanks for your comments and time!

Comment: Yur question's title is wrong and confusing.

Comment: The title's still wrong. You seem to be confusing between $\;f\;$ and $\;F\;$ .

Comment: I am aware that they are different functions. I just wrote the title that way to make the question a little shorter. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: But you have a wrong statement in the title. I came here to say that you are trying to prove something wrong, but now I see a totally different question.

Comment: You are right. I wrote something that is out of place. Would this title be better? Thank you, @Mark.

Comment: The result you claim is false. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3516923/72031).

Comment: The answer in previous comment has link to another answer which shows that if $F'$ exists in a neighborhood of $c$ and $f$ is continuous at $c$ then $F'$ is also continuous at $c$.