# If $f(x)=0$ for $x\in (1/(n+1),1/n]$ and $f(x)=x^2$ for $x\in (1/n, 1/(n-1))$, and $F(x)=\int_{-1}^x f$, is $F'$ continuous at $0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, derivatives

Let $f$ be the function
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 0, \text{ if } x \in \left (\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n} \right ] \\ x^2, \text{ if } x \in \left (\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n-1} \right ] \end{cases}$$

for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and define

$$F(x)=\int_{-1}^x f$$

Is $F'$ continuous at $0$?

As far as I can tell, it isn't, and my reasoning is as follows.

$f$ is continuous between $\left ( \frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n} \right ]$ and between $\left (\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n-1} \right ]$, so by the first fundamental theorem of calculus, $F'(x)=f(x)$ in these intervals. However, at points $1/n$ $F'$ is not defined.

Therefore, every interval containing $0$ contains points where $F'$ is undefined.

From this I conclude that $F'$ is not continuous because there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $\delta>0$ we have $\forall x$, $|x|<\delta \land \lnot(|F'(x)-F'(0)|<\epsilon)$, where the last negation comes from the fact that $F'(x)$ is not defined so the expression is false.

Comment: For the purposes of this question, the bottom integration limit can be any number smaller than $0$. On the other hand, I am now confused by your comment given that in another question I asked this week someone said it doesn't matter that a function being integrated isn't defined at one of the integration limit endpoints.

Comment: The integral can be written it's okay. But later on, the interval will be modified while integrating, at least like this : $$\int_{-1}^x f(t)dt=\int_{-1}^x 0.1_{]\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}]}(t)dt+\int_{-1}^x t^2 1_{]\frac{1}{n},\frac{n+1}{n}}(t)$$.