# Meaning of a theorem regarding the limits of derivatives?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

I'm confused about this theorem which is sometimes associated to the Darboux theorem for real functions.

Let $f: dom(f)\subseteq\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function continuous in a point $x_0 \in dom(f)$ and differentiable in a neighbourhood of $x_0$ (except for the point $x_0$).

If the $\lim_{x\to x_0}f'(x)=l \in  \mathbb{R} $ then $f'(x_0)=\lim_{x\to x_0}f'(x)$.

The theorem is easily proved using de l'Hopital theorem.

I don't really understand the consequences and the meaning of this theorem.

If a function is such that  $f(x_0)=\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$ the function $f$ is continuous in $x_0$ , so does the theorem imply that, under those conditions, the derivative of the function is continuous in $x_0$ ?

I read somewhere that this theorem (and the one of Darboux) imply that $f'$ does not have jump discontinuities, but nothing else can be said about it. If so, I can't understand how $f'$ could have other kinds of discontiuities, removable or essential.

What can one say about the continuity of $f'$, using this theorem (and the theorem of Darboux)?

Thanks in advice for your help

Comment: Consider $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x)$, $x\ne0$; $f(0)=0$. $f'$ is not continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: In that case the $\lim_{x\to x_0}f'(x) \nexists $ so the hypotesis are not satisfied

Comment: This was to address your concern in the last sentence of your seventh paragraph.

Comment: Maybe interesting: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/622738/discontinuities-of-the-derivative-of-a-differentiable-function-on-closed-interva.