# Reaching the conclusion that $f((a -\delta, a+\delta ))$ is not connected when $f$ has the IVP and $a$ is a simple discontinuity

Tags: limits, connectedness

I am trying to prove "a function with the intermediate value property cannot have simple discontinuities", inspiring myself with [this SE reply](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4602578/1021982).

Consider $f$ with the Intermediate Value Property and suppose it has a simple discontinuity. Then, $f(a)$, $r$ and $l$ cannot be all identical (where $r$ is the right-handed limit of $f$ at $a$ and $l$ the left-handed one).

Applying an adapted version of the definition $4.33$ from Rudin PMA (which [has a typo actually](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4678513/alternative-book-for-infinite-limits-and-limits-at-infinity-for-a-real-functio), see [here also](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Egbergman/ug.hndts/m104_Rudin_notes.pdf)) we have:

- $f((a- \delta , a)) \subseteq (l- \epsilon , l+\epsilon )$
- $f((a,a+\delta )) \subseteq (r-\epsilon , r+\epsilon )$
- $f(a) \subseteq (f(a) - \epsilon , f(a)+ \epsilon )$

Taking the union of these $3$ bullets, we have:

$$f((a-\delta , a+\delta)) \subseteq (l-\epsilon , l+\epsilon) \cup (r-\epsilon , r+\epsilon )\cup (f(a)-\epsilon , f(a)+\epsilon )$$

But, from here I cannot reach the same conclusion as in the answer because $f((a- \delta , a+ \delta))$ could very well be a subset of, say, $(l-  \epsilon, l+ \epsilon)$ and hence, be connected.

PS: I'm sorry that the $\epsilon$'s and $\delta$'s in the bullets are not very rigorous, but I think the idea is correct.

Comment: Simply choose $\epsilon$ less than $|r-l|/4$. (By the way, your usage of "be included in" is wrong: you mean "be a subset of". It is the _elements_ of an interval, such as $l$, that are included in that interval.)

Comment: @TonyK your $\epsilon$ does not work. E.g. $l=r.$

Comment: @AnneBauval: Yes, you are right. I was conflating simple discontinuities with jump discontinuities, but they are not the same.

Comment: @TonyK https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset : "$A$ is a subset of $B$ may also be expressed as [....] $A$ is included (or contained) in $B$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $ l,r$ are not both equal to $f(a),$ assume wlog $l<f(a).$ Let $\epsilon:=(f(a)-l)/2.$ Then for $\delta>0$ small enough,
$$f((a-\delta,a))\subseteq(l-\epsilon,l+\epsilon)$$and$$l+\epsilon<f(a)$$
hence $f$ does not have the IVP on $(a-\delta,a].$